# MOSS Web Parts or .aspx pages/controls

Tags: sharepoint, deployment, design-patterns, web-parts

When developing in MOSS I would be interested to hear peoples views on whether they choose to wrap functionality in web parts or to create .aspx pages and deploy those to MOSS and how best to make that decision.

Answer (score 3):

Web Parts are reusable across multiple pages. So if I develop a UI that is only usable once, I create .aspx pages. But if I need something that is usable on multiple pages or if I don't know/can't control where it will be deployed to, I create a Web Part.

Comment: good to hear, that was my approach currently. Have you considered using fieldcontrols in a page layout as opposed to more traditional .aspx pages?

Comment: Not really, mainly because I didn't spend the time investigating them and because I usually have some back-end classes generating the data I need to display anyway (I almost never directly display data from a list, usually there is always some processing involved anyway)